# Agrupar y sumar campos de funcion

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Estoy realizando una consulta con una función en SQL Server. Una de las columnas necesita agruparla por tipo de actividad en tres grupos. He conseguido hacerlo, ahora necesito que agrupe esas filas por Actividad y sume el tiempo (seg). Cuando coloco el grupo de Actividad tengo un error.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select  cod_actividad, 
    Fecha_inicio, 
    Fecha_fin, 
    seg,
    case 
        when Cod_actividad = 1 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 46 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 47  
            THEN 'Cerrada' 
            when Cod_actividad = 11 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 25' or  
                 Cod_actividad = 30 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 32 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 33 or
                 Cod_actividad = 34 or  
                 Cod_actividad = 41 or
                 Cod_actividad = 70  
            THEN 'no trabaja' 
            else 'working' end AS Actividad 
        from [myFunction] ('27/09/2022','26/10/2022')
```

Esto muestra el siguiente resultado:
[image: Query]
Quiero agrupar por actividad con lo cual me quedaran tres lineas y me sume los seg. Puedo prescindir de las columnas de fecha.

Quiero conseguir algo asi:
[image: Resultado esperado]

Espero se entienda

Gracias

Comment: ¿Que base de datos estas utilizando? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion en la pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el resultado de tu actual consulta como fuente de datos para una nueva consulta la cual agrupa los datos por `Actividad`.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM(T.seg) AS seg,
  T.Actividad
  FROM (
    SELECT
        Cod_actividad, 
        Fecha_inicio, 
        Fecha_fin, 
        seg,
      CASE
        WHEN Cod_actividad = 1 or 
          Cod_actividad = 46 or  
          Cod_actividad = 47  
          THEN 'Cerrada' 
        WHEN Cod_actividad = 11 or  
          Cod_actividad = 25 or  
          Cod_actividad = 30 or  
          Cod_actividad = 32 or  
          Cod_actividad = 33 or
          Cod_actividad = 34 or  
          Cod_actividad = 41 or
          Cod_actividad = 70  
          THEN 'No Productiva' 
        ELSE 'Productiva' 
      END AS Actividad 
    FROM [myFunction] ('27/09/2022','26/10/2022')
  ) AS T
GROUP BY T.Actividad
```

Comment: También se podría hacer usando CTE, pero sería básicamente lo mismo.